# Getting ! instead of comparison sign < in cases

Tags: cases

I get errors when I use the bellow code , such as in the first line the first < before alpha , gives me an ! instead of < , I tried many solutions by putting $ sign ,but I wasnt successful

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}  

\begin{document}
\begin{cases}
$
  35 < \alpha < 85 \\

  35 < c < 75 \\

  0.5 mm < T < 1 mm 
$
\end{cases}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Place the `$` *outside* of the `cases` environment.  More preferable would be `\[...\]` for display style.  Also, the `mm` are being interpreted as math variables.  Use instead `\text{mm}` or even look into the `siunitx` package.

Comment: If I put the $s *outside* the `cases` environment, your code works fine for me (though you may want `\[` and `\]` to make it a display, rather than inline maths).

Comment: As has been mentioned multiple times, please consult one or more of the many basic LaTeX introductions. A little investment at the beginning to learn properly will save you much time debugging basic errors like this in the future.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please, invest some time in reading a basic guide to LaTeX.

The `cases` environment must be initiated in math mode, that is between `$...$` (but not commonly, because this would build an inline formula) or inside

```
\begin{<mathenvironment>}
...
\end{<mathenvironment>}
```

where `<mathenvironment>` stands for `equation`, `align`, `alignat`, `flalign` `gather` or `multline` (or *-variant thereof). See the `amsmath` documentation for the various environments.

When running your example file, LaTeX stops with

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.5 \begin{cases}
```

that just repeats what I said above: `\begin{cases}` needs math mode. Now what happens? TeX inserts a `$` before `\begin{cases}` and goes on.

When it builds `cases`, it does an alignment (in text mode) where each cell is implicitly started with `$` and ended with the matching `$`, so each cell is back in math mode. When the explicit `$` you insert is scanned, it matches the implicit one at the beginning, so math mode is *exited*. When you try `<` in text mode (without loading the `T1` encoding), `¡` is printed: there is an explanation of the phenomenon, but the point is that your input is *wrong* to begin with.

As a proof something is going wrong we have the following error message:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.7   35 < \alpha
```

because also `\alpha` should only appear in math mode.

There's another couple of errors, but they're irrelevant. *Never* overlook error messages: the first one is usually the most important and the following ones can be just caused by it (not in this case, actually).

Better coding

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
  35 < \alpha < 85 \\
  35 < c < 75 \\
  \SI{0.5}{\mm} < T < \SI{1}{\mm}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Use `siunitx` for correctly typesetting units.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much , I replaced this code, worked great , best regards

Comment: But why community wiki?